# Symmetries of octahedron with $2$-faces action

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-actions, symmetry

[image]

Want to do the $2$-faces action. We use the Orbit stabilizer theorem. Let $X$ be the set of faces (any face can go to any face), $X=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 \}$. Where $1,2,3,4$ are the front faces of the picture and the rest are the back faces of the picture.

$|X|=|G:G_1|=|G|/|G_1|$ so $|G|=8|G_1|$ so we need to find $G_1$, which is the stabilizer at $1$.

We can do three symmetries with planes, red to red, purple to purple and blue to blue. And then there is the identity rotation. So far we have $4$ symmetries. What are the last two? Because we need to find $6$ symmetries in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three rotational symmetries that fix the face $1$; one is the identity, one is $\sigma := (238)(457)$, and the other is $\sigma^2 = \sigma^{-1}$.

Comment: The rotation $\sigma$ permutes the three vertices of face $1$, so its axis must be the line through the center of that face (and the center of the octahedron). Since $\sigma$ has order $3$, it must be a rotation by $\frac{1}{3} \cdot 360^{\circ} = 120^{\circ}$.

Comment: So what degree rotation is $\sigma ^2$?

Comment: What is the order of $\sigma^2$?

Comment: Just to confirm $\sigma ^2 = (238)(457)(238)(457)$ right?

Comment: Yes, but of course we can simplify that equation. (In fact, we don't need to compute anything, we can just visualize that action of $\sigma^2 = \sigma^{-1}$ on the faces.)

Comment: The computation is correct, but a rotation of $180^{\circ}$ would have order $2$...

Comment: Sorry I meant rotate anticlockwise 120 degrees to give (283)(475) correct????

Comment: Yes, that looks right to me (provided we're looking down on face $1$ from the outside).

Comment: At a glance they look good to me.